fine-tuned for the BERT model - what dataset do I need to tune the model
I would have one question related to Deep Learning.
If you have some time during the week and could explain one thing to me, I would appreciate it.
I am currently creating a project related to fine-tuned BERT. I am still considering the base or large version.
The project will be based on preliminary document analysis and extraction of the most important information extracted from the file. Cos along the lines of pre-checking documents for credit applications.
I have created additional tokens for BERT about 1500 according to WordPiece methodology.
I have a question about the dataset. Currently I have about 250 thousand sentences (each on a new line).
The quality of these sentences varies. There are no labels, because I want to do fine-tuned based on MLM (masking).
The quality of the dataset is average. There may be some noise and errors.
My question is whether it is better to do a fine-tuned, on a smaller number of sentences, e.g., select from a dataset of about 30-40 thousand (appropriately selected) + new tokens, or try to burn through resources and enable training on a full dataset ?
For the sake of time + computing resources, I prefer to ask the community first rather than burn through the environment several times each.
Regards,

If your downstream task involves contextual understanding (like embeddings), I think MLM is a good option. In the 2023 research paper "Textbooks Are All You Need", the authors experimented with training models on high quality (textbook quality) data concluding: "We hypothesize that such high quality data dramatically improves the learning efficiency of language models..". The tradeoff is difficult to quantify and is dependent on your downstream task, and the increase in quality of your higher quality data. Maybe train first on high quality data than on lower quality data if needed.

Sounds good.
Will try first with less data but better quality. Next week will do a fairly strong clean and data reduction.
It will be interesting to see what the result will be. I'll be sure to come back with information on how it worked out for us
